# Generate a data.frame column based on number of decades of row cell values

Tags: r

Having a data.frame like:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
  [1,]    1    6    7   10   23   22 
  [2,]    2   15   18   21   24   27
  [3,]   13   16   23   22   25   28
```

I want to create a new column of type string named "pattern". The values of "pattern" are generated by concatenating the numbers of decades for each cell value in row. So for the first row the value of pattern will be generated as following:

-for 1 the decade number is 0, 6 is 0, 7 is 0, 10 is 1, 23 is 2 and for 22 
      is 2. So we get 000122

For the whole data.frame the result should be:

```
     [Pattern]
 [1]   000122
 [2]   011222
 [3]   112222
```

I tried using for loops but it takes a lot of time for data.frames containing a big number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the integer division output to `data.frame` and `paste` the elements in each row with `do.call`

```
do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(m1%/% 10))
#[1] "000122" "011222" "112222"
```

---

Or loop through each row with `apply` by specifying the `MARGIN` as 1 and `paste`

```
apply(m1 %/% 10, 1, FUN = paste, collapse="")
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(1, 2, 13, 6, 15, 16, 7, 18, 23, 10, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
25, 22, 27, 28), .Dim = c(3L, 6L))
```